# How to dynamically bind data in WPF notify Icon window

Tags: sql, asp.net, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

Hello I want to create notify icon to my task-bar and when I click that icon one popup window open and that popup showing me which tasks are I have to complete today and also want to show today's appointment list.

[image]

**Doubts**

1. Suppose I get 10 task from database for today's date then All task should be display with scroll bar.
2. How to bind data with WPF control([textBlock])?
3. How to create [textBlock] control dynamically means Suppose I get task description from description column then it display otherwise description [textBlock] is not create.

I have refereed following link to achieve this.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon

but I really don't know how to bind data with WPF application.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the FancyPopup.xaml

Add:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TasksCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate/>
</ListView>
```

In the code behind you can set your view model like this:

```
public FancyPopup()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new PopupViewModel();
}
```

And then in your ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<TaskDataModel> tasksCollection;
public ObservableCollection<TaskDataModel> TasksCollection
{
    get
    {
        if (tasksCollection == null)
        {
            tasksCollection = new ObservableCollection<TaskDataModel>();
        }
        return tasksCollection;
    }
    set
    {
        tasksCollection = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("tasksCollection");
    }
}
```

Where TaskDataModel is class describing your data model.

```
public class TaskDataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TaskDataModel()
    {

    }

    private string taskName;
    public string TaskName
    {
        get { return taskName; }
        set
        {
            if (taskName != value)
            {
                taskName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TaskName");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use MVC. How to achieve using simple ado.net code??

Comment: This is not MVC. It is MVVM - M for Model(class for your data), V for View(that is the xaml part which is resposible for the look of your data or how you are presenting it) and VM for ViewModel(the part which connects the model with the view). My example is minimal and very easy to implement.
Binding usually needs some code to work for properly. I any of the code is not clear or your don't understand it ...just ask for more details.